# How to condense many FindSequenceFunctions into a single one?

Tags: integer-sequence

I have a function $f(n,k)$ that is rather large and complex, but if I hold $k$ constant and feed values into *Mathematica* over many $n$, I can get a closed-form expression for that $k$.

However, I can't seem to find a good way to feed the whole function into *Mathematica* due to structural reasons, but is there a way I can get a closed-form expression by chaining them somehow?

For example, if I have the `FindSequenceFunction` for $k=1$, $k=2$, $k=3$, etc, can I then run a similar `FindSequenceFunction` across all of these expressions and get a closed form for $f(n,k)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. However, it really depends on whether `FindSequenceFunction` can recognize the closed form of `f(n,k)`. Here is a contrived example to show that it is possible:

Suppose we know ahead of time that `f(n,k) = n^2 + k^2`.

```
In[1] := f[n_,k_] := n^2 + k^2
```

We will first let `FindSequenceFunction` return the closed-form solutions for `f` when `k = 1`, `k = 2`, `k = 3`, ...

```
In[2] := FindSequenceFunction[Table[f[n, 1], {n, 10}]]
Out[2] = 1 + #1^2 &
In[3] := FindSequenceFunction[Table[f[n, 2], {n, 10}]]
Out[3] = 4 + #1^2 &
In[4] := FindSequenceFunction[Table[f[n, 2], {n, 10}]]
Out[4] = 9 + #1^2 &
```

To generalize, let `fsf` be a table of these intermediate functions:

```
In[5] := Table[FindSequenceFunction[Table[f[n, k], {n, 10}]], {k, 5}]
Out[5] = {1 + #1^2 &, 4 + #1^2 &, 9 + #1^2 &, 16 + #1^2 &, 25 + #1^2 &}
In[6] := fsf = (#[n] & /@ %)
Out[6] = {1 + n^2, 4 + n^2, 9 + n^2, 16 + n^2, 25 + n^2}
```

We can then simply find the closed-form solution for `f(n,k)` as follows:

```
In[7] := closedForm = FindSequenceFunction[fsf][k]
Out[7] = k^2 + n^2
In[8] := closedForm == f[n,k]
Out[8] = True
```